# Using the Boadilla theme in beamer, there are previews of text that will appear later in the current slide - how to disable?

Tags: beamer, themes, preview

The question is contained in the title. I am writing a presentation using Boadilla theme in beamer/LaTeX. When I have a slide which uses \onslide<1->{hello} follow by \onslide<2->{second text}, you can see "second text" displayed faintly in grey on slide 1, before its onslide numbering. Is there a way to use this theme but remove these previews?

Comment: Try putting `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` in your preamble.

Comment: Perfect, if you want to post it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beamer` documentation describes the command `setbeamercovered{}` (currently in section 17.6), which offers control over how a covered item will appear. In your case you want to put `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` in your preamble, but other options include `transparent`, `dynamic` (varying degrees of opacity), `highly dynamic`, `still covered` and `covered again`. The opacity can be defined for most of these options by setting the `opaqueness` value.